# How do I batch convert dd/mm/yyyy HHMM to dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM

Tags: excel

I have several thousand entries and i'm trying to get the differences between two times. If I manually convert dd/mm/yyyy HHMM to dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM then I can use a simple =K-J formula in the next column to do this. But how do I get that darn colon into the many entries without having to manually go through and do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the TEXT function?

```
=TEXT([Your cell reference],"dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM")
```

Alternatively, if the original value is being stored as string you could try:

```
=MID([Your cell reference],1,LEN([Your cell reference])-2) & ":" & RIGHT([Your cell reference],2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried that but I gave it another shot, and unfortunately same result. When I convert both of the times using the TEXT function and then try to subtract using =K3039-J3039 i get a #VALUE! error.

Comment: My guess is the original value is being stored as a string. The second formula works for me.

Comment: =MID([Your cell reference],1,LEN([Your cell reference])-2) & ":" & RIGHT([Your cell reference],2) WORKED GREAT!!!! Thanks so much you are awesome!

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your title suggests a uniform format of "dd/mm/yyyy HHMM", which excludes variations such as "dd/mm/yyyy HMM", etc., and so guarantees a string length of 15 characters, then, assuming entries in `A1` and `B1`:

`=0+REPLACE(A1,14,,":")`

and

`=0+REPLACE(B1,14,,":")`

Or, without helper columns, and assuming that `B1>=A1`:

`=REPLACE(B1,14,,":")-REPLACE(A1,14,,":")`